# Simple jacorb program

Tags: java, javac, jacorb

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.huihoo.com/corba/jacorb/tutorial.html) to implement a server and client using jacorb. I used the same code and in step 2 when I want to compile the generated server.java class I got this error

```
javac server.java
server.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol: class serverOperations
    extends serverOperations, org.omg.CORBA.Object, org.omg.CORBA.portable.IDLEntity
            ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the directory containing the generated stub and skeleton code to your classpath. The JacORB jar is also required

```
javac -cp /path/to/stubcode:jacorb.jar:. Server.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking questions about JacORB on the jacorb-developer list (http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html)